# Do I need to purchase 2 Cloud SQL for HA?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I confuse about google cloud sql for sql server 2019 standard, my specs:

1X GCE Instance Application - 8CPU, 96GB Ram : SQLServer 2019 Standard, High Availability turned on  - Primary 500GB SSD, 500 for Backup (1 set), google calculator shows, the price is USD 2,986.76 per month.

As far as I know, we will need 2 instances if we want to run HA, question: will they bill us approx. 2x USD 2,986.76 in their monthly billing ?

Need advise.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming Question. It seems to be a support Question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question

Answer (score 2):

The question is tedious.

**YES** you will pay for 2 instances, you can see that in the [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/pricing)

**NO** you haven't to create 2 instances by yourselves. The HA mode do that for you, behind the scene. Explain in the [concept section](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/high-availability).

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question, will they bill us 2x because of HA

Comment: Yes, 2 instances (1 active + 1 HA), you will pay 2x, as presented in the pricing page.